# VBA: cannot automatically recalculate Excel formula after updating it -- needs manual interaction

Tags: vba, excel, excel-2010

In VBA, I am updating the formula in a cell (which works ok), but automatic recalculation does not work:

```
updated_formula = "=COUNT(Sheet1!A3:A" & nr_points & ")"
Cells(x, y).Formula = updated_formula
ActiveWorkbook.Save
Cells(x, y).Calculate
```

The formula simply counts the number of existing rows in another sheet. When I run the macro, the cell's value in the function textfield is correct, but in the cell itself I have `"#NAME?"` and I need to press <kbd>ENTER</kbd> in the function to recalculate the formula.

Am I expecting too much of Excel? Or am I doing something wrong?

EDIT: Screenshot of the situation -- this is what I see after running the macro. 
(Sorry for the black censoring, have to maintain anonimity for the client company)

[image]

Comment: Which sheet `Cells(x, y)` is in?

Comment: @Siddharth It's in a sheet which is not the same as Sheet1, but within the same Excel file. I'm updating the post with a screenshot, maybe it makes my description clearer.

Comment: No that is ok. I was assuming that it is in the same sheet. There is nothing wrong with the code. It should work... Maybe i missed something.. let me have a look again...

Comment: What is `ANZAHL`? I thought it was `COUNT`

Comment: Ah! I have never worked with a german version. gimme a moment... I have a feeling why this is happening.. let me test something and get back to you...

Comment: @Siddharth Great, thanks for investigating :-) PS. Believe me, I wish I didn't have to work with the German version, either... :D

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22837/discussion-between-siddharth-rout-and-cristina)

Comment: Try this.. Change `Cells(x, y).Formula = updated_formula` to `Cells(x, y).FormulaLocal = updated_formula` Does it work?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

After seeing your screenshot, it became clear.

Change

`Cells(x, y).Formula = updated_formula`

to

`Cells(x, y).FormulaLocal = updated_formula`

Comment: `+1` for clarity and understanding what OP needs... ;)

Answer (score 0):

Your code works fine on my sheet and updates calculated value immediately after macro run. Please make sure **Calculation Options** are set to "Automatic": Ribbon **Data** tab > Calculation Options > Automatic.

Comment: Perhaps that matters - I'm using Excel 2007.

Comment: Thanks, it was solved in the comments: I am using the German version of Excel, and due to the idiotic decision to have Excel functions localized, I had to use FormulaLocal instead of Formula. This is just the latest problem in a string of many caused by these stupid localized functions!

Comment: @Cristina glad to know you solved, Siddharth Rout - thanks for the suggestion - this is nice piece of experience for me for future use!

Comment: The moral here: whenever you are working with non-English Excel, keep your eyes peeled for extra "fun" :-)

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late post, but I had a similar issue and what worked for me was to change

```
Cells(x, y).Calculate
```

to

```
Cells(x, y).Dirty
```