# Set function of Excel Cell via Interop - LOCALIZED

Tags: excel, localization, interop, excel-formula

I want to add an Excel Function to a Cell via C# and Interop (Office 2010).

Let's take SUM for example.

Using `WorksheetFunction` ist **NOT** what I want, because this is a one time function call.
So what I want is

```
Xl.Range range = SomeWorksheet.Range["A1"];
range.Formula = "=SUM(A2:A5)";
```

This is fine if you are using an english version of excel but is an error in every other language.

I found [this overview](http://www.software.maninweb.de/news/261/279/Comparison-and-function-list-of-Excel-2010-2007-and-2003/d,news_details.html) but this would mean to handcode the localization. Not so very nice.

What I need is s.th. like

```
string localizedFunctionName = Xl.Application.GetFuncName(Func.Sum);
```

Kind Regards
Martin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following:

```
range.FormulaLocal = "=SUM(A2:A5)";
```

---

Read more here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/aa205983%28v=office.10%29.aspx and this question: [VBA: cannot automatically recalculate Excel formula after updating it -- needs manual interaction](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361270/vba-cannot-automatically-recalculate-excel-formula-after-updating-it-needs-m/14362262)